# This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I'm new to typescript, converting an array into an option tag but got the error, My interface is**

```
interface ViewEmployeeManagerPostType {
  id: string;
  user: string;
  department: string;
  experience: string;
  height: string;
  value: string;
  children: React.ReactNode[] | React.ReactNode;
};
```

**My Array**

```
const [ManagerEmployee, setManagerEmployee] = useState<ViewEmployeeManagerPostType[]>([]);
```

**Component return ()**

```
----
----
<option value="">Select Employee ID</option>
    {ManagerEmployee.map((option) => 
       <option key={count++} value={option}>
          Employee ID = {option}
       </option>
     )}
----
----
```

**I'm getting error on the option opening tag and value**

Answer (score 2):

As you see, there's an unambiguous requirement: `'children' prop expects a single child`, thus

```
children: React.ReactNode;
```

And when you provide array of React nodes to `children` component prop, just wrap them with `<Fragment>` or `<>` like this

```
children={
   <>
    <option value="">Select Employee ID</option>
    {ManagerEmployee.map((option) => 
       <option key={option.id} value={option.value}>
         Employee ID = {option.id}
       </option>
   )}
   </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interface, you need to use `children: React.ReactNode;` instead of `children: React.ReactNode[] | React.ReactNode;`

In addition to that, the `option` represents the `ManagerEmployee`  object and hence you cannot simply print it out using `{option}`. Instead, you need to use `value={option.value}` and `Employee ID = {option.id}`

```
----
----
<option value="">Select Employee ID</option>
{ManagerEmployee.map((option) => 
   <option key={option.id} value={option.value}>
      Employee ID = {option.id}
   </option>
)}
----
----
```

Comment: I tried it but got another error. As you can see ManagerEmployee is an array so how can I access it by value={option.value}

Comment: ManagerEmployee is an array. but when you map it, the `option` represents a single instance of MangerEmployee.